# CXXFLAGS modification of Qt pro file?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, makefile, qmake

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Configuring the GCC compiler switches in Qt, QtCreator, and QMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987062/configuring-the-gcc-compiler-switches-in-qt-qtcreator-and-qmake)

I would like to use `-O1` instead of `-O2` in my makefile (`CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS`) for my Linux build. My understanding of how these makefiles are generated based on the .pro file is somewhat lacking. This is because the version of Qt combined with the version of G++ I am using has instabilities when `-O2` is present.

Presently, I am running a replacement script, after I run qmake, which does this:

```
sed -i 's/\-O2/\-O1/g' AllProjects/Makefile.Release
```

This is a ghetto solution. A much better solution would be to modify the .pro file somehow to pass along these directives. I am not sure how `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS` are being generated though.

I have tried passing a

```
linux-g++-{ 
      CFLAGS += -O1
      CXXFLAGS += -O1
      CONFIG += -O1
}
```

which did not work.

Comment: linux-g++-{
   QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -O1
} doesn't work, linux-g++-{
   QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += -O1
} also doesn't work, I should have mentioned that I tried this in my solution.

Comment: I'm thinking my check is a bit too tight too, since it seems like QMAKE_CXXFLAGS SHOULD work.

Comment: it does, I use it. Try `linux*` instead as a condition.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You were very close. What you want is:

`QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -O1`

If you would like to apply flags to just the release build, then you can use this:

`QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += -O1`

You also probably want to change your condition to be a little more flexible. In summary, something like this:

```
*-g++* {
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -O1
}
```

More in the documentation here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/qmake-variable-reference.html#qmake-cxxflags

Comment: Thanks, my flag was ALSO too tight, exactly like you suggested.

Comment: @Brian: yea, you had a trailing dash which killed it.

Comment: If the flag you are setting also relates to linking, you will also need to set eg. QMAKE_LFLAGS += -m32

Comment: This doesn't work for me. You solution changed `-O2` to `-O1 -O2`, which is hardly helpful.

Comment: qmake docs moved to https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmake-variable-reference.html