# C++ Qt - How to add "-std=c++11" to the makefile which is generated by qmake?

Tags: qt, c++11, makefile, qmake

I'm developing a program in Qt. Its makefile is generated automatically from the .pro file. I need to use some code which need the -std=c++11 flag to be set up for g++. Where in .pro should I add this flag? (changing only the Makefile won't work since it gets overwritten by the newly generated one, each time I build the project).

Comment: possible duplicate of [CXXFLAGS modification From My .pro File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837106/cxxflags-modification-from-my-pro-file)

Comment: add `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11` in your .pro file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable c++11 in qt creator 2.7.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948382/how-to-enable-c11-in-qt-creator-2-7-0)

Comment: Which Qt version are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Configuring the GCC compiler switches in Qt, QtCreator, and QMake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987062/configuring-the-gcc-compiler-switches-in-qt-qtcreator-and-qmake)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You may find it tempting to insert the specific flag (which you mention)

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
```

in your .pro file, but this will insert just that flag on your behalf.

That's insufficient. The right way is to insert instead

```
CONFIG += c++11
```

in your .pro file. Two or three necessary changes are then made by `qmake`:

1. `-std=c++11` is inserted.
2. `-stdlib=libc++` is inserted.
3. If you're on a Mac, `-mmacosx-version-min=10.6` becomes `-mmacosx-version-min=10.7`. (Perhaps some similar change is necessary on other OSes or OS versions.)

(A similar issue at [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17457803/qt-linux-qmake-cxxflags-std-c11-equivalent-for-windows) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22925717/adding-qmake-cxxflags-std-c11-to-pro-file-in-qt-not-workingon-linux-12-0).)

Comment: @Wildling So you used CONFIG += c++11 and you got c++11 compilation issues?

Comment: Thanks for explaining why `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS` is insufficient. +1

Comment: Tweaking CONFIG does not work for Qt4. Haven't tested for Qt5.

Answer (score 78):

You can add the following to the Qt .pro for C++11: -

```
CONFIG += c++11
```

As of Qt 5.4, C++14 can be enabled with

```
CONFIG += c++14
```

Comment: I added this, ran qmake and rebuilded the project, but I'm still getting the same error (it's regarding vector initialization), and I don't see the c++11 in g++.
    
../SignalAnalyzer/TestConfiguration.cpp:12:61: error: in C++98 'TestConfiguration::measurementPoints' must be initialized by constructor, not by '{...}'

Comment: Can you add the full error to the question? You only asked where to add the config command and stated nothing about an error.

Comment: What if my project does not have a .pro file (when using qtcreator as editor only). Which of the qt generated files do I then modify (modification of .config does not seem to make a difference).

Comment: Using CONFIG += c++11 appears to only be supported by qmake version 3.0 and later (the version included with Qt5). Earlier versions of qmake seem to ignore this value, so you may have to use QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11 in Qt4 and older.

Comment: I think I can confirm @josmith42's theory.  If I have a project with a kit pointing to Qt4.x then I can't use `unique_ptr` unless I abuse `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS`.   I change that to Qt5, then `unique_ptr` suddenly works, if I only have `CONFIG += c++11`

Comment: With Qt 5.5.1 (from online installer) on Debian Wheezy with GCC 4.7.2-5 I get `Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: c++11`, probably because 4.7 has more like experimental C++11..?

Comment: strange, I had QMake v3.0, qt5.2.1. The CONFIG+=c++11 was not enough, it actually required QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11

Answer (score 23):

You can change CXX flags :

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
```

I usually set it as :

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic
```

Comment: Definitely do not use this.

Comment: @becko "Definitely" is a bit strong, but specifying switches like that will not be portable. It'll work on *gcc*, and probably *clang*, but not on *MSVC*.

Comment: Worked for me! Centos, Qt4

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Snow Leopad 10.6.8 and gcc 4.9, I had to use

```
CONFIG += c++11
```

instead of

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
```

The latter was simply not recognized.

Answer (score 0):

```
CONFIG += c++11
```

in .pro file appears to work for me with the Qt4 SDK after installing qt5-default on my Ubuntu desktop:

```
sudo apt install qt5-default
```

Anyway the generated makefile contains a `-std=c++0x` option I suspect to be sufficient to compile my C++11 code.