# connect QPushButton via lambda

Tags: qt, c++11, lambda

I am trying to connect `QPushButton` to lambda expression:

```
      QPushButton* loadTextFileButton = new QPushButton("load");
      connect(loadTextFileButton, &QPushButton::clicked, [](){
         qDebug()<<"clicked";
      });
```

Compiler gives me an errors like: **No matching function to call "MyClass::connect(..."**

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure your class inherits from QObject and has the Q_OBJECT macro defined: http://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_Q_OBJECT_Macro_Meta_Object.php

Comment: `connect` is a static method of QObject. You can write `QObject::connect(...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connect function, which is part of Qt's signal and slots mechanism is Qt's extension to C++.

The connect function is actually a [static function of QObject](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#connect), so you can use it from anywhere, by simply including QObject: -

```
#include <QObject>
...
QObject::connect(itemPtr1, SIGNAL(someFunction()), itemPtr2, SLOT(someOtherFunction());
```

The objects itemPtr1 and itemPtr2 are pointers to instances of classes that are derived from QObject and support signals and slots.

In order for a class to use the signal and slot mechanism, it must inherit from QObject and declare the Q_OBJECT macro:-

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{
     Q_OBJECT // the Q_OBJECT macro, which must be present for signals and slots

     public:
          MyClass(QObject* parent);

     signals:

     public slots:

     private:
           void StandardFunction();
};
```

As this class inherits QObject, it now has direct access to the connect function, allowing calling connect directly:-

```
 QPushButton* loadTextFileButton = new QPushButton("load");
 connect(loadTextFileButton, &QPushButton::clicked, []()
 {
     qDebug()<<"clicked";
 });
```

Finally, Qt 5 introduced a new syntax for signals and slots: -

```
connect(loadTextFileButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MyClass::StandardFunction);
```

You may have noticed that the advantage here is that the signal can be connected to a function that is not declared as a slot. In addition, using this syntax provides compile time error checking.

Comment: I have got other buttons in my program. Ordinary connect(&, SIGNAL(), &, SLOT()) works great in the program. Now I have cheked that Qt 5 new syntax also work without error. However when I am trying to use connect with lambda compiler gives an error. I have got a lot of "simple" buttons in my program, so I dont want to create a bunch of functions with one or two line in it.

Comment: Have you set your .pro file to use C++ 11 ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19398438/c-qt-how-to-add-std-c11-to-the-makefile-which-is-generated-by-qmake/19398489#19398489

Comment: @ Merlin069 I have put CONFIG+=C++11 line in .pro file. Now it works! I thought that C++11 is used automatically in QT5