# How to catch websocket connection error

Tags: c++, qt, websocket

I'm opening a url from Qt/c++ client like,

```
m_webSocket = new QWebSocket();
m_webSocket->open("wss://192.123.1.44:8087");
```

I want catch any errors in connection. How do I do that?
I've connected to signal `QWebSocket:error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError error)`, but I never get it triggered even if my server is not running.

**Edit**:
I'm connecting to error signal as below,

```
m_webSocket = new QWebSocket();
connect(m_webSocket, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError error)), this, SLOT(onWebSocketError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError error)));
m_webSocket->open(url);
```

This seems to be not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Connect to the QWebSocket [error](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebsocket.html#error-2) signal, before opening the socket.

```
QWebSocket* pWebSocket = new QWebSocket;
connect(pWebSocket, &QWebSocket::error, [=](QAbstractSocket::SocketError error)
{
    // Handle error here...
    qDebug() << pWebSocket->errorString();
}

pWebSocket->open("wss://192.123.1.44:8087");
```

*Note that this connection uses a lambda function, which requires [C++ 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19398438/c-qt-how-to-add-std-c11-to-the-makefile-which-is-generated-by-qmake/19398489#19398489). Connection to a slot in the usual manner will also work.*

Without C++ 11, use a standard (Qt 5) connection: -

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT

   public:
       MyClass(QUrl url);

   protected slots:
       void Error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError error);

   private:
       QWebSocket* pWebSocket;
};


MyClass::MyClass(QUrl url)
{        
    QWebSocket* pWebSocket = new QWebSocket;
    connect(pWebSocket, &QWebSocket::error, pMyClass, &MyClass::Error);
    m_webSocket->open(url);
}
```

As [QObject::connect](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect) returns a [QMetaObjectConnection](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject-connection.html), which contains an [overloaded bool operator](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject-connection.html#operator-bool), you can check the return from the call to connect, to ensure that a valid signal and slot was found, and valid arguments provided: -

```
// Old-style connection
if(!connect(m_webSocket, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)), this, SLOT(onWebSocketError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError))) )
{
    qDebug() << "Failed to connect to QWebSocket::error" <<  endl;
}
```

However, this is largely redundant, as a failed connection usually produces debug output informing you of this issue, from within Qt's connect call.

> NOTE, in the old-style connection syntax, the argument list does not name the arguments, only the type is provided. Adding a name will produce a failed connection.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've edited my question. Please have a look and let me know if this a correct way to handle the error signal.

Comment: Yes, but if you're using Qt 5, it's better to use the new connection syntax, which will error at compile time if it's wrong; *connect(m_webSocket, &QWebSocket::error, this, &MyClass:: onWebSocketError);*

Comment: I've connected to error signal as mentioned in edit. Still not able to catch the error.

Comment: If you're using the Qt SIGNAL and SLOT macros, check the return from the  call to connect.

Comment: I'm still not able to figure out the problem.

Comment: In your example connect, you've named the arguments for QAbstractSocket::SocketError. This will fail to match, causing the failed connection at run-time. If you're using Qt 5, I strongly suggest using the newer connection style, as it checks the connection is valid when compiling.

Answer (score 9):

As described in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebsocket.html#error-1):

> Note: Signal error is overloaded in this class. To connect to this signal by using the function pointer syntax, Qt provides a convenient helper for obtaining the function pointer as shown in this example:

```
connect(webSocket, QOverload<QAbstractSocket::SocketError>::of(&QWebSocket::error),
[=](QAbstractSocket::SocketError error){ /* ... */ });
```

Of course, instead of lambda function, you could connect to a normal one, but the `QOverload` part is important.

Comment: This was the magic I needed. I couldn't get the compiler to stop complaining. Thank you.