# Qt- Don't show QWidget if it has been already shown

Tags: c++, qt

I want to use Animation which toggled by clicking on specific button. Here is my code:

source:

```
    void MainWindow::menuClicked()
    {
    //if animation is shown , try to hide it 
        if (m_menuOpend){
            m_animation = new QPropertyAnimation(widgetAnimate, "geometry");
            m_animation->setDuration(200);
            m_animation->setStartValue(QRect(0, 43, 400, 5*windowsHeight/6));
            m_animation->setEndValue(QRect(-300, 43, 400, 5*windowsHeight/6));
            m_animation->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::Linear);
            m_animation->start(QPropertyAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);
            m_menuOpend = false;
        }else{
            //if widget has not created
            if (!widgetAnimate){
               widgetAnimate = new QWidget (this);
            }
        widgetAnimate->show();
        m_animation = new QPropertyAnimation(widgetAnimate, "geometry");
        m_animation->setDuration(200);
        m_animation->setStartValue(QRect(-300, 43, 400, 5*windowsHeight/6));
        m_animation->setEndValue(QRect(0, 43, 400, 5*windowsHeight/6));
        m_animation->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::Linear);
        m_animation->start(QPropertyAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);    
        m_menuOpend = true;
    } 
}
```

header:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

    private:
        QWidget *widgetAnimate;
};
```

Actually I give an error on

```
widgetAnimate->show();
```

because it's skip

```
if (!widgetAnimate)
```

condition every time. Any suggestion to avoid creating multiple widget?

Comment: How is initialized your widgetAnimate variable? It is global? in the class? what is the starting value?

Comment: @AdrianMaire I've edited my question.

Comment: Have you initialized `widgetAnimate` to `0` or `nullptr`? You can't use `if (!widgetAnimate)` otherwise.

Comment: No , I haven't. how to initialize that? @yzn-pku

Comment: Initialize `widgetAnimate` variable in the `MainWindow` constructor.

Comment: Alternatively, if you're using [C++11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19398438/c-qt-how-to-add-std-c11-to-the-makefile-which-is-generated-by-qmake/19398489#19398489), you can initialise the variable when you declare it in the header *QWidget *widgetAnimate = nullptr;*