# Qt change picture on timer

Tags: c++, qt, qtimer

I'm trying to change the image on QLabel in Qt.

At first, I did the basic set image as follows:

```
void MainWindow::setMainDisplayNew(QString imageName){
     QPixmap pix7 = imageName;
     QPixmap pix8 = pix7.scaled(QSize(720,480), Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
     ui->mainDisplay->setStyleSheet(imageName);
     ui->mainDisplay->setPixmap(pix8);
}
```

Now I want to change this so I can pass 2 arrays. List of images and duration they should appear for and I want the display to show them for the indicated duration.

```
        void MainWindow::setMainDisplay(QString imageName[], int size)
{
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        QTimer * timer = new QTimer(this);
        timer->setSingleShot(true);
        connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, [=](){
            setMainDisplayNew(imageName[i]);
            timer->deleteLater(); // ensure we cleanup the timer
        });
        timer->start(3000);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

With the help of the responses, I reached the above code. I am sending the 3 images. It is display the final image after 3 seconds and stays as is... Any help?

Comment: ``while(true)`` makes your application never get to process the timeout-event.

Comment: I'm not sure why this has been down-voted; it's a reasonable question and a simple mistake to make for those who have had little experience with event-driven programming.

Comment: the timer->start(3000) line is wrong. That will make all the timers fire at the same time. You want them to be staggered, so you need to use a different variable for each timer start time (i.e. first one at 0 ms, second one at 3000ms, third one at 6000ms, and so on).

Comment: @ScottG thanks that seems to cover it up! One final question, how can I make it run continuously?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while(true){
```

This is your problem. Qt is an [event-driven framework](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html). The *while(true)* prevents events from being processed. Such events include the timeout from the QTimer and updating of the GUI. You need to allow the function to exit.

In addition, you're not cleaning up your timers, so you're leaking memory every time you enter the function (although that's currently only once!). You can clean up with a call to deleteLater.

Using [C++ 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19398438/c-qt-how-to-add-std-c11-to-the-makefile-which-is-generated-by-qmake/19398489#19398489), it would be something like this: -

```
for(int i=0; i<mySize; i++)
{
    QTimer * timer = new QTimer(this);
    timer->setSingleShot(true);

    connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, [=](){
        setMainDisplayNew(imageName[i]);
        timer->deleteLater(); // ensure we cleanup the timer
    });

    timer->start(duration[i]);
}
```

Comment: You're right, and although you could get it to work by adding a 'QApplication::processEvents();' inside the while loop, it would not change the fact that this is bad design in the first place.

Comment: Indeed, processEvents should not be called here.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight thanks for the quick response!
I implemented it, it is giving me timeout() was not declared in this scope. Any advice?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the scope in the connect call. It should be *&QTimer::timeout*. I've updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight I think it should be &QTimer::timeout ?? it was giving no matching function with timeout(). it is still not working properly, I updated question

Comment: Correct, it's &QTimer::timeout, as it takes a reference to a function. This also means that using this connection syntax allows the connection to any class function, not just those defined as a slot.