# Json QtNetworkReply to QByteArray

Tags: c++, json, qt

I need to do a request in Qt/c++ to get a JSON file, and then parse it and fill my object.

The request seems good, and "it looks like" my QtNetworkReply reply is filled.

But after many attempts, I still don't understand how can I convert it into a QbyteArray (I don't even know if it's the right thing to do...), for being able to convert it into my class.

Here's my code :

```
QNetworkAccessManager networkManager;
QUrl url("https://api.myjson.com/bins/uvki"); //url from a free json host
QNetworkRequest request;enter code here
request.setUrl(url);
QNetworkReply* reply = networkManager.get(request);
QByteArray reponse;

if (reply == NULL)
{
    std::cout << "Damn" << std::endl;
    exit(2);
}
reponse = reply->readAll();
if (reponse == NULL)
{
    std::cout << "i hate you" << std::endl;
    exit(1000);
}
```

I might have done some stupid stuff, I only have 2 days of c++

Can you tell me how I can convert my "reply" into my "reponse"?

Comment: You need to start with Qt basics first: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html

Comment: Then you should investigate documentation about `QNetworkAccessManager`: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html

Comment: You do not have a valid reply directly after sending the request. Wait for the data to return ``QNetworkRequest::finished()``.

Answer (score 2):

The answer provided by @MichaelBoone is correct.

In addtion, with [C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19398438/c-qt-how-to-add-std-c11-to-the-makefile-which-is-generated-by-qmake/19398489#19398489), you can simplify the code by using Qt 5's `QObject::connection` syntax and a lambda function

```
QJsonDocument document;
QNetworkReply* pReply = networkManager.get(request);

connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, [=](){  

  // the reply will return here
  QByteArray response = pReply->readAll();
  document = QJsonDocument::fromBinaryData(response);

});
```

Qt 5's connections syntax has the advantage of compile-time verification of the connection, which is not present when using the `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` macros.

Answer (score 1):

You have to connect the finished() signal from  reply object, or from the NetworkManager to get the results.  You will also need to make *reply a class member, or you won't be able to access it within your handler SLOT.

```
QNetworkReply* reply = networkManager.get(request);
connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(YourFunctionHere()));

void YourFunctionHere(){
    //handle the data
}
```

QNetworkReply is a non-blocking function, like most QT Network functions, it is asynchronous.  By the time you are reaching your conditional  if statement to check the reply, it hasn't yet received a response from the network.

As far as handling the download afterwards, you are correct in using a QByteArray.

> QByteArray QIODevice::readAll()
>
> This is an overloaded function.
>
> Reads all available data from the device, and returns it as a
>   QByteArray.

From there you use QJsonDocument.

> QJsonDocument QJsonDocument::fromBinaryData(const QByteArray & data,
>   DataValidation validation = Validate)
>
> Creates a QJsonDocument from data.

Edit - Sorry I don't have the reputation to comment, but I feel The answer provided by TheDarkKnight lends itself better to the one-off nature of a "Reply" and is less encumbered by having to create a new slot.  lambdas are just very cool, and the compile time verification is nice.