# QT: passing strongly typed enum argument to slot

Tags: c++, qt, enums

I have defined a strongly typed enum like this:

```
enum class RequestType{ 
    type1, type2, type3 
};
```

Also I have a function defined as below:

```
sendRequest(RequestType request_type){ 
    // actions here 
}
```

I'd like to call the `sendRequest` function every 10 seconds so in a simple case I would use something like this:

```
QTimer * timer = new QTimer(this);
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(sendRequest()));
timer->start(10000);
```

Since I need to pass some arguments to `sendRequest` function I guess I have to use `QSignalMapper` but as `QSignalMapper::setMapping` can be used straightforwardly only for `int` and `QString`, I cannot figure out how to implement this. Is there any relatively simple way for it?

Comment: Keep in mind that strongly typed enums need to be registered as metatype.

Comment: @user3528438 can you show an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're [using C++ 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19398438/c-qt-how-to-add-std-c11-to-the-makefile-which-is-generated-by-qmake/19398489#19398489), you have the option of calling a lambda function in response to `timeout`

```
QTimer * timer = new QTimer(this);
connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, [=](){

    sendRequest(request_type);

});
timer->start(10000);
```

Note that the connection method here (Qt 5) doesn't use the SIGNAL and SLOT macros, which is advantageous, as errors are caught at compilation, rather than during execution.

Answer (score 2):

You can create `onTimeout` slot. Something like this:

```
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(onTimeout()));
```

and in this slot:

```
void onTimeout() {
  RequestType request;
  // fill request
  sendRequest(request);
}
```