# error: no template named 'enable_if_t' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'enable_if'?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, clang, qmake

I'm compiling with Qt 5.11.3 on macOS 10.13.6. The clang version used by Qt is:

```sh
$ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -v
Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

But I'm receiving this error:

```cpp
error: no template named 'enable_if_t' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'enable_if'?
using FloatingOnly = std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, O>;
                     ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
                          enable_if
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/type_traits:423:63: note: 'enable_if' declared here
template <bool, class _Tp = void> struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS enable_if {};
                                                              ^
```

### Tried

So far, I have done these, with no effect:

```cpp
// On source *.cpp file

#include <type_traits>
```

```
# On project *.pro file

CONFIG += c++17
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++17 # for Clang
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -stdlib=libc++ # xcode_settings
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
```

### Error resolved

I just used these and the error got resolved:

```
CONFIG += c++14
CONFIG += c++17
```

Comment: It looks like the c++17 flag may not be used. Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19398438/c-qt-how-to-add-std-c11-to-the-makefile-which-is-generated-by-qmake

Comment: @MorningDewd `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11` didn't work :(

Comment: Change to MAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++14

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The template alias `enable_if_t` is not available in C++11; it was added in C++14, as were most of the other type trait `*_t` versions (C++17 added `*_v` versions for boolean traits as `inline constexpr` variables).