# error: no template named 'is_same_v' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'is_same'?

Tags: c++, xcode, qt, std, clang++

This is a followup for [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64281680/3405291) which is already resolved. But then, I receive this error:

```
error: no template named 'is_same_v' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'is_same'?
    !std::is_same_v<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type, void>, O
     ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
          is_same
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/type_traits:831:61: note: 'is_same' declared here
template <class _Tp, class _Up> struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS is_same           : public false_type {};
                                                            ^
```

Based on [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64282324/3405291):

> ... it was added in C++14, as were most of the other type trait `*_t` versions ... C++17 added `*_v` versions as inline constexpr variables ...

So, `is_same_v` is added by C++17. But I already add C++14 and C++17 to QMake by:

```
CONFIG += c++14
CONFIG += c++17
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++14
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++17
```

Is it possible that XCode (Clang) lacks some C++17 features? My Xcode version is 9.4.1 and my Clang++ version is:

```
$ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -v
Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

### Code

There are both C++14 `*_t`  type trait versions and C++17 `*_v` versions in the code which is from a repository with many contributors:

```cpp
template<class T, class O = T>
using IteratorOnly = std::enable_if_t<
    !std::is_same_v<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type, void>, O
>;
```

### Observation

When I use `CONFIG += c++14` in QMake project file, I receive only this error:

- `enable_if_t` is fine and `is_same_v` is bad

> error: no template named 'is_same_v' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'is_same'?

When I use `CONFIG += c++17` in QMake project file, I receive both these error:

- both `enable_if_t` and `is_same_v` are bad

> error: no template named 'enable_if_t' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'enable_if'?

> error: no template named 'is_same_v' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'is_same'?

Why?

Comment: C++14 and C++17 flags are mutually exclusive. You only compile with a *single* standard version. Just remove all references to C++14.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica When I remove all references to C++14, and keep just C++17, I receive unknown `enable_if_t` error!

Comment: Sounds like a bad installation of the standard library/compiler. The `_t` type traits are available in C++14 going forward. Meaning they are available in C++17 too, and so specifying that isn't supposed to make them stop working.

Comment: I don't think xcode 9 has full c++17 support, is there a reason you're using an old version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tool chain was *not* capable of C++17. Therefore, eventually, replaced `std::is_same_v` with `std::is_same` with [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64292594/3405291) ...