# How to replace std::is_same_v with std::is_same

Tags: c++, std

I have this code containing `std::is_same_v` available with C++17. But I've stuck with C++14 due to toolchain limitation.

```cpp
template<class T, class O = T>
using IteratorOnly = std::enable_if_t<
    !std::is_same_v<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type, void>, O
>;
```

How can I replace `std::is_same_v` with `std::is_same`? Is there any workaround to be able to compile the code with just C++14?

Comment: `std::is_same<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type, void>::value`.

Comment: Check e.g. [this `std::is_same` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same). It show (a possible) definition of `std::is_same_v`, from which it should be possible to reverse it to get the `std::is_same` usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error got resolved by @Someprogrammerdude comment about a `is_same_v` *helper variable template* defined [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same). My final code is

```cpp
#ifdef My_OLD_TOOL_CHAIN

template< class T, class U >
inline constexpr bool is_same_v = std::is_same<T, U>::value;

template<class T, class O = T>
using IteratorOnly = std::enable_if_t<
    !is_same_v<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type, void>, O
>;

#else // My_OLD_TOOL_CHAIN

template<class T, class O = T>
using IteratorOnly = std::enable_if_t<
    !std::is_same_v<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type, void>, O
>;

#endif // My_OLD_TOOL_CHAIN
```

Comment: On a totally unrelated note, all symbols beginning with double underscore are reserved in all scopes. See e.g. [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)