# Simple program won't compile with qtcreator

Tags: c++, qt, gcc

I installed qt 4.7.4 and gcc 4.6.1. I tried to compile this program but it won't compile for me:
Why cannot I compile this code?

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc,argv);
    int a[] = {1,2};
    for (auto e : a)
    {
        cout << e << '\n';
    }
    return app.exec();
}
```

Error:
C:...\main.cpp:9: error: 'e' does not name a type

Comment: I think I speak for everyone when I say we're sorry to hear that. What is your question? Care to tell us what the error was?

Comment: @Widor the question (implicitly) is why cannot I compile it, but I'll update it.

Comment: What command are you using to compile it?  (your using c++11, and so you will need to tell g++ this via compiler flags: try `g++ file.cpp --std=c++0x`)

Comment: Most probably your compiler does not understand this new c++ feature.

Comment: @Tom where (via QTCreator) am I suppose to put those options

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`for (auto e : a)`
is a range based for loop from the c++11 standard. You need to enable the c++11 in gcc with the -std=c++0x command line.

Comment: where (via QTCreator) am I suppose to put those options ?

Comment: I never used QtCreator. But this link should answer the question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987062/configuring-the-gcc-compiler-switches-in-qt-qtcreator-and-qmake

Comment: yes, this seems to solve the problem, great pity you cannot set it via some dialog. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For me this works (g++ 4.6.1, Qt 4.7.1):

```
g++ --std=c++0x -I$QTDIR/include/QtGui -I$QTDIR/include \
    test.cpp -L$QTDIR/lib -lQtCore -lQtGui
```

Answer (score 1):

You need --std=c++0x compiler flag.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that qtcreator (and qmake) does not feed the compiler with the flag instructing it to use C++2011.

Answer (score 0):

First, you want to be sure that your C++ file is compiled with the C++11 dialect (ie using [-std=c++0x](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options) flag to `g++`) since you use the `auto` type inference feature.

Then, I think that your `for` loop might not be valid. Perhaps you want `a` to be a `std::vector<int>`