# Configuration for optimizing QtCreator compiler

Tags: c++, qt, g++, qt-creator, compiler-optimization

I'm using QtCreator in Windows 7.

I want to configure it to use third level optimization (`-O3`) for c++ compiler.

How can I do this to speed up my code and what changes are necessary?

Comment: **[See here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3042278/170194)**

Answer (score 20):

Try to add next lines to your .pro file:

```
# remove possible other optimization flags
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE -= -O
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE -= -O1
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE -= -O2 

# add the desired -O3 if not present
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE *= -O3
```

Comment: I did it. But I can't see any improvement. Maybe I should think about rebuilding Qt with -O3

Answer (score 0):

Add these line's to your .pro file if you want a small application size

`QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Os -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 -finline-small-functions -momit-leaf-frame-pointer`

If you want a faster application , consider using -O2 instead of -Os

refer [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) for more options