# How to add options to gcc in qt creator?

Tags: c, qt, gcc, opengl, command-line-arguments

Qt has been my choice of IDE for several years but this is crazy frustrating.

I'm trying to use openGL in my C project, but none of the functions have a defined reference. I google the issue and [find this lovely page (second to last response)](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-154550.html). I try this out and it works flawlessly:

```
gcc main.c -lGL -lglut
```

But using the terminal instead of the built-in functionality of Qt creator is... undesirable. So I google how to add options to gcc with qt, I find [this stackoverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987062/configuring-the-gcc-compiler-switches-in-qt-qtcreator-and-qmake), but it doesn't work, at all. And I tried all sorts of things like

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -lGL -lglut
```

and

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS += -lGL -lglut
```

and (desperately)

```
OPTIONS: -lGL -lglut
```

I don't know, I can't figure out how I'm supposed to add options to gcc in Qt so that my functions are no longer undefined.

Maybe I need a new IDE with a more straight forward compile function...

**EDIT!** Iskar Jarak was right, I had to add it to libs like so:

```
LIBS += -lGL -lglut
```

This is in the .pro file by the way.

Comment: Try [`LIBS += -lGL -lglut`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#libs) instead. Note that this goes in your `.pro` file.

Comment: That's it!! Thank you!!

Comment: Glad to hear it, I've added my comment as a proper answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [`LIBS += -lGL -lglut`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#libs) to your `.pro` file.

`QMAKE_CXXFLAGS` is for C++ compiler flags like `-std=C++0x`